# Avoiding Hard Coding in Apex following Best Practices

Tags: salesforce, apex

In reference to the best practice #10 avoiding hard coding IDs, is my code considered to follow best practice without using Lists or Maps ??

[Best Practices Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

```
trigger RecordTypeTester on Account (before update) {
    for (Account acc: trigger.new)
    {
        if(acc.RecordTypeId == [SELECT Id  from RecordType WHERE sObjectType = 'Account' AND IsActive = True AND Name = 'Health Care' LIMIT 1].Id)
        {
            //some code

        }
        else if (acc.RecordTypeId == [SELECT Id  from RecordType WHERE sObjectType = 'Account' AND IsActive = True AND Name = 'Hi-Tech' LIMIT 1].Id)
        {
            //some code
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any hard-coded ID here (?).

Comment: Yes. I did'nt use any hard coded IDs.But I was asking about the alternate implementation that I tried compared to the one mentioned in the Best Practices article which uses Lists and Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize constant first

```
public final static Id INVOICE_SUMMARY_RECORD_TYPE_ID = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Invoice Summary').getRecordTypeId();
```

and then, use it in a method

```
 if (oppItem.RecordTypeId != INVOICE_SUMMARY_RECORD_TYPE_ID)
```